# An old sci-fi story about an Earth ship orbiting Jupiter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, in the 90's, I read a sci-fi story in an airline mag. It was about an Earth ship orbiting Jupiter where they sent Earth men down to the surface transforming them into these enormous Jupiter beings but were distressed that none of their guys were coming back. I remember a line from the latest guy they sent down; he said "Up there I'll only be a human".

Comment: "Desertion" by Clifford Simak.

Comment: See this old question & answer (among others): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/looking-for-title-of-sci-fi-short-story-about-attempts-to-colonise-planet-venus

Comment: You can read "Desertion" here; is that the one you're looking for? https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v34n03_1944-11_cape1736#page/n63/mode/1up

Comment: In "Desertion" the guy takes his dog with him. The ending: “I can’t go back,” said Towser.  “Nor I,” said Fowler. “They would turn me back into a dog,” said Towser. “And me,” said Fowler, “back into a man,” **Is that it?**

Answer (score 15):

Possibly [Desertion](http://bestsciencefictionstories.com/2009/05/17/desertion-by-clifford-d-simak/) by Clifford D. Simak?  It pre-dated the similar Poul Anderson "Call Me Joe" and I think matches a little closer to your description".

> Years ago, in the 90's,

Written in 1944

> I read a Sci-Fi story in an airline mag.

It is a short story vs. Call Me Joe which is a novelettte so better fits what might be in an airline mag.

> It is about the director of a Jovian survey dome who keeps losing men to Jupiter’s open atmosphere.It was about an earth ship orbiting Jupiter where they sent earth men down to the surface transforming them into these enormous Jupiter beings

Fowler has lost four men to Jupiter’s raging atmosphere and is getting ready to send out a fifth. The journey should be relatively easy – each man is transformed into a native Jovian Loper and then is supposed to go to the first survey stake and return.

> but were distressed that none of their guys were coming back.

Doesn’t sound too difficult does it? Nope.  But apparently it is because no one has ever come back! Now as the rest of the people in the survey dome are talking about the disappearances, and the biologists are insisting that it has nothing to do with the Loper transformations, Fowler decides to take a huge risk to find out exactly what is happening to his men.

> I remember a line from the latest guy they sent down. He said "Up there I'll only be a human". Can anyone ID that story, I've looked all over the net with no hits. Thanks.

As the title notes, it is not a problem with the transformation. The men are actually leaving.

Comment: Final two lines from **Desertion** are: *"They would turn me back into a dog,"* said Towser.
*"And me,"* said Fowler, *"back into a man."*  Which matches *"up there I'll only be a human"*

Comment: *Desertation* is part of Simak's famous future history fixup *The City*.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Are you sure you meant "fixup"? Because that implies formulaic "to spec" stories to me. Which admittedly happened during the time period in question.

Comment: @Spencer a "fix-up" is a novel cobbled together from short stories. There is nothing particularly demeaning about the name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fix-up

Comment: What @Spencer said.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was the story and I've found it online and read it. There was more to it than I remembered, but my recollection of it being a good read was very accurate. I'm going to also look up Call me Joe as I'm a big Poul Anderson fan too.
I'm amazed at how fast I got the answer to my question here, I've been google searching for the story for years with no luck. Thanks again....

Comment: This should be a comment on beichst's answer, not an answer in its own right. Also, please remember to accept their answer to confirm that your query has been solved. Glad you managed to find what you were looking for!