# Transformed for Jupiter life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story; written before 90s; where a man is in charge of a program to settle Jupiter; where they had developed some way of transforming human into Jupiter adapted life. Seems to work; but no one comes back.
Man transforms self and dog in desperate attempt to figure out: turns out life so wonderful they didn’t go back either.

Comment: This is almost undoubtedly ["Desertion"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84442/101407) by Simak; check out the linked answer and see if it matches what you remember.  Posting a comment because it's been answered here many times.

Comment: That is it, thanks. Feel free to put this as an answer, David and I'll accept it... or put it as duplicate.