# Short story about an astronaut who lands on Jupiter with a dog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story about an astronaut sent to Jupiter to try and find what had happened to other astronauts who had been sent there and never returned once they left the spaceship. The astronauts could be transformed into a beings that could survive on Jupiter without space suits. Despite the hostile atmosphere, once this astronaut like the ones before him, experienced the Jovian world, he never came back to the space ship because from his new point of view, Jupiter was beautiful. Also, I think the Astronaut had a dog.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: This is "Desertion" by Simak, and has been answered here several times.

Comment: That is to say, of course, that does not make this a bad question. You provided some good details, and the system isn't always good for notifying you that there is already a matching question and answer in the system.

Comment: Hi. I'm the one who posed this question and I am impressed and grateful to get the answer (Clifford Simak's "Desertion").  Although this is an old question to this group, let me tell you why I've been thinking of this story... There is an amazing book (Ed Yong's,  An Immense World) that is not Sci-Fi, but describes how animals perceive the world (that humans cannot perceive). Simak's story of how a human (and a dog), given the ability to sense Jupiter the way the Lopers do, are transformed by the knowledge of what they have been missing is a perfect link to this book. You should read it!  Tx!

Comment: See OP confirmation comment above.

Answer (score 9):

Jupiter, astronauts, a dog, and transformation suggests Clifford D. Simak's "[Desertion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16029136-desertion)"

> Two volunteers who have had their bodies turned into “Lopers” so that they can survey the surface of Jupiter disappear. The administrator can’t in good conscience send another volunteer to look for them, so he transforms himself and his faithful dog into Lopers.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/looking-for-title-of-sci-fi-short-story-about-attempts-to-colonise-planet-venus?noredirect=1&lq=1