# Classic SF short story. Men transmit consciousness into bodies that can live in Jupiter

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, planets

The protagonist is the leader of the team of scientists exploring inside the gas of Jupiter.
The scientists sent to explore have their consciousness transmitted into bodies that can survive there. I don't recall if they are flesh bodies or robots.
It seems as if the transfers go well and the new bodies with scientists in are moving around Jupiter. However the plan was to return to their human bodies and report their findings but none of them ever return.

The leader says to prepare to transfer his dog's consciousness to Jupiter. The others are shocked that he would do that to his dog, who cannot volunteer like a human can. The protagonist just says I am not going to leave him behind without me.

So human and dog are transferred to bodies in Jupiter. Find they can communicate telepathically there.Human apologises for not always understanding the dog in tbe past. The dog readily forgives him. They run and play together.

Living in Jupiter is

> heavenly. They are both estatic. The former dog says "If I go back they will turn me back into a dog." The former human says. "And they will turn me back into a man."

Comment: [Desertion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84440/looking-for-title-of-sci-fi-short-story-about-attempts-to-colonise-planet-venus). It has been asked about [many, many times already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+desertion+simak).

Comment: If it were not “Desertion” it would be “Call Me Joe” by Poul Anderson.

Comment: It is Desertion  If John wants to write an answer I will tick it.

Comment: Or maybe someone can close this as a duplicate and link to another time it was asked.

Comment: @JudithJones Thanks for confirming it :-)